# Does the sequence $\{f_n\}$ converge in $L^1$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Consider the sequence of functions $f_n\in L^1(\Bbb R)$ defined by $f_n(x)=n\chi_{(0,1/n)}(x)$ for $x\in\Bbb R$. Does the sequence $\{f_n\}$ converge in $L^1$?

**Attempt.** I think it doesn't. Suppose there exists a function $g\in L^1(\Bbb R)$ such that $f_n\to g$ in $L^1$. Then by Minkowski inequality we have
$$0=\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f_n-g\|_1\geq \lim_{n\to\infty}|\|f_n\|_1-\|g\|_1|=\lim_{n\to\infty}|1-\|g\|_1|=1-\|g\|_1$$ implies that $\|g\|_1\geq 1.$ On the other hand,
$$0=\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f_n-g\|_1=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\Bbb R}|f_n(x)-g(x)|dx.$$
Here, I am not sure that we are able to use Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem. If so, we get $\|g\|_1=0$, contradiction. Also, it is easy to see that $f_n$ converges to the zero function pointwise. Thanks!

Comment: $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$ implies $f_n \to f$ a.e. So by your last remark $f=0$. But then $\|f_n - f\|_{L^1} = 1 \not \to 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: If it converges it can only converge to the zero function. This is because convergence in $L^{1}$ implies a.e. convergence for a subsequence and the point-wise limit is $0$. Now $\int |f_n-0|=1$ so $(f_n)$ does not converge in $L^{1}$.